# Detect difference of match in list context with a capturing vs non-capturing regexp?

Tags: regex, perl

According to [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches)

> ... in scalar context, `$time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/` returns a true or false value. In list context, however, it returns the list of matched values `($1,$2,$3)` .

But I can't find an explanation of what is returned in list context if the pattern matches when there are no capturing groups in the regexp. Testing shows that it is the list `(1)` (single element, integer 1). (Ancillary question - will it always be this, where is it defined?)

This makes it difficult to do what I want:

```
if (my @captures = ($input =~ $regexp)) {
    furtherProcessing(@captures);
}
```

I want `furtherProcessing` to be called if there is a match, with any captured groups passed as arguments. The problem comes when the `$regexp` contains no capturing groups because then I want `furtherProcessing` to be called with no arguments, not with the value `1` which is what happens in the above. I can't test for `(1)` as a special case, like this

```
if (my @captures = ($input =~ $regexp)) {
    shift @captures if $captures[0] == 1;
    furtherProcessing(@captures);
}
```

because in the case of

```
$input = 'a value:1';
$regexp = qr/value:(\S+)/;
```

there is a captured value in `@captures` that happens to look the same as what I get when the `$regexp` matches but has no capturing groups.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`$#+`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@LAST_MATCH_END) to find out how many groups were in the last successful match.  If that's 0, then there were no groups and you have `(1)`.  (Yes, it will always be `(1)` if there are no groups, as documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Matching-in-list-context).)

So, this will do what you want:

```
if (my @captures = ($input =~ $regexp)) {
    @captures = () unless $#+; # Only want actual capture groups
    furtherProcessing(@captures);
}
```

Note that `$#+` counts all groups, whether they matched or not (as long as the entire RE matched).  So, `"hello" =~ /hello( world)?/` will return 1 group, even though the group didn't match (the value in `@captures` will be `undef`).

Comment: Tested and it works a treat. Also a thumbs up for answering my ancillary question. Thanks.

Comment: or (perhaps overly obfu for some) `my @captures = ($input =~ $regexp) x !!$#+`

Comment: @ysth, I think `$#+` all by itself is probably obfuscated enough. :-)

Comment: Isn't `$1` a lot less obfuscated--especially if you're only using it as a predicate: `furtherProcessing( defined( $1 ) ? @captures : ())`

Comment: @Axeman, there's no guarantee `$1` will be defined if there are groups in the regex.  The first group might not have matched.  Look at my "hello" example.  There's a group in the regex, but `$1` is `undef`.